# How can I return an arbitrary derived class of an abstract generic class and call its generic methods?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, design-patterns, abstract-class

I've got an abstract class that uses variable template.

```
template <class T>
class Abstract
{
public:
    virtual void print(T t) = 0;
};
```

There can be any derivatives of the class like so:

```
class A : public Abstract<std::string>
{
public:
    void print(std::string str)
    {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public Abstract<int>
{
public:
    void print(int number)
    {
        std::cout << std::to_string(number) << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Now I want a function to return one of these derivatives so I can execute the print method. And here is my Problem:

```
template (class T); // error here
Abstract<T> &f(int n) // what should the return type look like?
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        A a{};
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        B b{};
        return b;
    }
}

int main()
{
    A a{f(0)};
    a.print("foo");

    B b{f(1)};
    b.print(42);

    return 0;
}
```

So how is it be possible to return a class with unknown parameter type and call its methods?

I already tried returning derived classes without templates which works fine. As soon as templates are added code wont compile. I also tried void* and reinterpret_cast. Problem here is that I have manually to decide to what type to cast to.

So how can I return an arbitrary superclass of an abstract generic class and call its generic methods?

Comment: For the "error here" part you should use the correct template syntax, like `template<class T>`

Comment: `f` returns a reference to a local which is not a good idea in general.

Comment: Usually, "superclass" is usually used to refer to the base class, not the derived ones.

Comment: You could give `std::variant` a try.

Answer (score 1):

I think inheritance is the wrong approach here. Instead I would use *specialization* instead:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo;

template<>
struct Foo<std::string>
{
    void print(std::string const& s)
    {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }
};

template<>
struct Foo<int>
{
    void print(int value)
    {
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }
};
```

Then you don't need a selector to pick the object to create, just the correct type:

```
int main()
{
    Foo<std::string> f1;
    f1.print("hello");

    Foo<int> f2;
    f2.print(123);
}
```

---

If you really need a factor function, then it could be created like this:

```
template<typename T>
Foo<T> create()
{
    return Foo<T>();
}
```

And use like

```
int main()
{
    auto f1 = create<std::string>();
    f1.print("hello");

    auto f2 = create<int>();
    f2.print(123);
}
```